# AWS - Route 53 - Redirect to EC2 instance without subdomain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance

I'm trying to point my domain name to my ec2 instance without a subdomain. I setup an elastic IP on my instance, the DNS is ready to go, my domain is setup, but the two records that I have are below:

[image]

I simply want my domain to point to the instance, no subdomain, simply dc.al -> EC2... what would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an A record without anything before the domain. Leave empty. Use the elastic IP as the value.